# WordPress: How to rename image during upload with current date?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, regexp-replace

Is there any plugin that can add the current date with the filename while uploading to the wordpress library?

```
Example:

Normal   : example_image.jpg
Sanitized: 23_12_2020-example_image.jpg
```

Is it possible to do that on WordPress, please help !!

Answer (score 1):

```
function image_name_with_date($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    /* check image is file or not */
    if ($info['extension']== 'jpg' || $info['extension'] == 'jpeg' || 
   $info['extension'] == 'gif' || $info['extension'] == 'png') {
       $name = basename($filename, $ext);
        return date('d_m_y').'-'.$name.$ext;                                                      
    } 
 return $filename; //if file is not image
}                                                                   
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'image_name_with_date, 10);
```

Comment: Its my pleasure to fix your issue..Feel free to ask me if you have problem .Thank you